# Find the largest number of distinct integers that sum to n

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, integer, integer-partitions

## The Task

Given an input positive integer `n` (from 1 to your language's limit, inclusively), return or output the maximum number of distinct positive integers that sum to `n`.

## Test Cases

Let `f` define a valid function according to the task:

The sequence for `f`, starting at 1:

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, ...
```

As a larger test case:

```
>>> f(1000000000) // Might not be feasible with brute-forcers
44720
```

## Test Code

For any test cases not explicitly given, the output of your code should match the result of the following:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println((int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(2*x + 1./4) - 1./2));
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU67DsIwDNz7FR4TEOEhNsQHMDB1RAwhBEhJnZK4UIT49mJQQNxy1t357Epf9Sg0Fqv9uXd1EyJBxZpqyXlVGo1o46Jv2p13BozXKcFaO4RHUQAjG4k0MV2D20PNtigpOjxutqDjMUlOQ0auhGRgCWhvX0GU90S2Vg7l4hd2SNBxLhmFtqMVkvhz80ZoSTV8jTwKwST5QTqpgw8his@YLpHEbNDBEKZqPJcwevNM5q5nUTz7fjr54AU)

Comment: Can it be 0-indexed?

Comment: @totallyhuman "it" being the answers? Because this isn't about a list...

Comment: Yes. Can the output for **1** be **2**?

Comment: @totallyhuman No. This is about the distinct partitions of specific numbers.

Comment: This is [OEIS A003056](https://oeis.org/A003056).

Comment: If it helps anyone, this is equivalent to finding the last triangle number, and returning its index in the sequence of triangle numbers.

Comment: I feel insignificant most every time I stumble into the codegolf stack.  The answers and the comments are much more than humbling.  The questions are usually interesting too but with his comment @JeppeStigNielsen just throws in the completed blueprints when we are still contemplating the floor area.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
ÅTg<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cGtIus3//0bGAA)

Perfect tool for the job.

`ÅT` yields the list of **Å**ll **T**riangular numbers up to and including **N** (unfortunately includes 0 too, otherwise it would be 3 bytes), `g<` gets the len**g**th and decrements it.

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
R+\»ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9IO@bQ7iPd/w@3P2pa8/@/kQEA)

Somewhat efficient. This sequence increments at triangular numbers, so this just counts how many triangular numbers are smaller than *n*.

Explanation:

```
        # Main link
R       # Range, generate [1..n]
 +\     # Cumulative sum (returns the first n triangular numbers)
   »    # For each element, return the maximum of that element and 'n'
    ċ   # How many elements are 'n'? (implicit right argument is n)
```

Comment: In the explanation, you surely mean "how many numbers are smaller than _or equal to_ _n_"

Comment: @LuisMendo See the new explanation.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to H.PWiz.*

```hs
(!!)$do x<-[0..];x<$[0..x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzX0NRUVMlJV@hwkY32kBPL9a6wkYFxKiI/Z@bmJmnYKtQUJSZV6KgopCbWKCQphBtqKdnbBD7/19yWk5ievF/3eSCAgA)

This returns the **nth** element of the whole numbers where each **i** is replicated **i + 1** times.

Comment: I can't help but ask what "succ" is

Comment: Yeah, I know lol. `succ` stands for `successor`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 36 bytes

```
<>(())({()<(({}())){<>({}[()])}>{}})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/38ZOQ0NTU6NaQ9NGQ6O6FsjWrAaKVddGa2jGatbaVdfWav7/b2kAAA)

This uses the same structure as the standard division algorithm, except that the "divisor" is incremented every time it is read.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 19 bytes

```
n->((8*n+1)^.5-1)\2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D9P105Dw0IrT9tQM07PVNdQM8bof1p@kUYeUNJQR8HIQEehoCgzrwQooKSgawck0jTyNDU1uSCiSnpgoATjGxrAAEI5QkxT8z8A)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
×8‘½’:2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wdItHDTMO7X3UMNPK6P///0bGAA)

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Ḥ+4İ¤½_.Ḟ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9qZWxsef//4bikKzTEsMKkwr1fLuG4nv///zIz)

This is longer than <s>Dennis’</s> and DJ’s, but this time **on purpose**. Very, very *efficient*.

Comment: [lol I love precision](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjiXaJkc2HFpyaG@83sMd8/7//285CkgGegYA "Jelly – Try It Online")

Comment: @totallyhuman Use `M`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 82 bytes

Whitespace added for "Readability"

```
(())

{
    {}

    ((({})[[]]))

    ([({}<(())>)](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}

}{}{}{}

([]<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYsxDoBACAR7XmG5FBZak/vIheIsTIzGwpbwdoSjWWYWjm9c73o@444AmImMlhxzmgnAnHtXrW6ankbqtrFCGrOlSJTm5gaIeSsyT64gqsJrQdf8iNj2Hw)

Comment: [Competition as always](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152637/56656)

Comment: Who'd've thought that combining two unreadable languages, Whitespace and Brain-Flak, could be considered "readable"!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
function(n)rep(1:n,1:n+1)[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPsyi1QMPQKk8HiLUNNaPzYv@naRgZa/4HAA)

Creates the vector of `1` repeated `2` times, `2` repeated `3` times, ..., `n` repeated `n+1` times and takes the `nth` element. This will memory error either because `1:n` is too large or because the repeated list with `n*(n+1)/2 - 1` elements is too large.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 29 bytes

```r
function(n)((8*n+1)^.5-1)%/%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPU0PDQitP21AzTs9U11BTVV/V6H@ahpGx5n8A)

Computes the value directly, using the formula found in [alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152569/67312). This should run with no issues, apart from possibly numerical precision.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 30 bytes

```r
function(n)sum(cumsum(1:n)<=n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNPs7g0VyO5NBdEGVrladrY5mn@T9MwMtb8DwA)

Counts the triangular numbers less than or equal to `n`. This'll possibly memory error if `1:n` is large enough -- for instance, at `1e9` it throws `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3.7 Gb`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
lh{I#./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyej2lNZT///fyNjAA)

Filter-keep the integer partitions which are `I`nvariant over deduplication, grab the `h`ead and obtain its `l`ength.

#### Validity proof

<sub><sup>Not very rigorous nor well-worded.</sup></sub>

Let **A = a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + ... + a<sub>n</sub>** and **B = b<sub>1</sub> + b<sub>2</sub> + ... + b<sub>m</sub>** be two distinct partitions of the same integer **N**. We will assume that **A** is the *longest* unique partition. After we deduplicate **B**, that is, replace multiple occurrences of the same integer with only one of them, we know that the sum of **B** is less than **N**. But we also know that the function result is increasing (non-strictly), so we can deduce that the longest unique partition  **A** always has at least the same amount of elements as the count of unique items in other partitions.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
+/+\∘⍳<⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRtfe2YRx0zHvVutnnUtQgopmBsAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 8 bytes

Closed formula solution.

```
*8Ä ¬É z
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=KjjEIKzJIHo=&input=MTAwMDAwMDAwMA==)

---

### Explanation

Multiply by 8, add 1 (`Ä`), get the square root (`¬`), subtract 1 (`É`) and floor divide the result by 2 (`z`).

---

### Alternative, 8 bytes

Port of [DJMcMayhem's Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152530/58974).

```
õ å+ è§U
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SDlKyDop1U=&input=MTAwMDAwMA==)

Generate an array of integers (`õ`) from 1 to input, cumulatively reduce (`å`) by addition (`+`) and count (`è`) the elements that are less than or equal to (`§`) the input (`U`).

Answer (score 2):

## Befunge, <s>32</s> 20 bytes

```
1+::1+*2/&#@0#.-`#1_
```

[Try it online!](http://befunge.tryitonline.net/#code=MSs6OjErKjIvJiNAMCMuLWAjMV8&input=MTAwMDAwMDAwMA)

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 12 bytes

```
int(√(2Ans+1/4)-.5
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 18 bytes

```javascript
x=>(x-~x)**.5-.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/C1k6jQreuQlNLS89UV8@0xuB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahAQxoanKl5RdpVNgaWlfYGBoASW1tTVTFFZqa/wE)

Comment: Is this always correct? I'm not certain `floor((sqrt(8x+4)-1)/2)` (your formula) and `floor((sqrt(8x+1)-1)/2)` (correct formula) give the same result for every `x`.

Comment: @ETHproductions I could bluff and say "yes", but I think the more honest answer is that you should try to develop your own hypothesis and figure out if / why it mirrors the same formula. I didn't come up with this approach by myself (I learned it from a different site) but I played around with it a bit. It's a very interesting approach and I don't want to dissect the frog so early.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure how to prove it directly, but I wrote a brute-forcer that does not find any failures under 100 million.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 28 bytes

```java
n->~-(int)Math.sqrt(8*n+1)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU7BTsMwDL33K6xJldJ1Ddu4IJVN4s7EYeKEOIR2KS6tExJ3UoXKr5d0Gwc0fHn2e89@rtVRZXX5MWJrjWOowyw7xkbO8@iK0x0VjIYm0XZvDRZQNMp72Ckk@IoALqxnxQGOBktogyb27JCql1dQrvLJyQrwaKh6JuX6J3twio0DDZuRsu13JpA42Sl@l/7TsbibU7pKbtZjflrUwTo5AGEDqzzAfcDlMnRp@nsdYN97PrTSdCxtiGctZvFtCdkW4nUZ02wBuAAtlbVN/@CnbwQmyTliiP670JD46w@hlzovDtEw/gA)

Because the example was really not well golfed :p

### Credits

- -2 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)

Comment: [28 bytes](https://tio.run/##bU7BTsMwDL33K6xJldJ1Ddu4IJVN4s7EYeKEOIR2KS6tExJ3UoXKr5d0Gwc0fHn2e89@rtVRZXX5MWJrjWOowyw7xkbO8@iK0x0VjIYm0XZvDRZQNMp72Ckk@IoALqxnxQGOBktogyb27JCql1dQrvLJyQrwaKh6JuX6J3twio0DDZuRsu13JpA42Sl@l/7TsbibU7pKbtZjflrUwTo5AGEDqzzAfcDlMnRp@nsdYN97PrTSdCxtiGctZvFtCdkW4nUZ02wBuAAtlbVN/@CnbwQmyTliiP670JD46w@hlzovDtEw/gA) "_Because_ your code _was really not well golfed_" ;p

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well, now it is! :o

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), <s>70</s> <s>56</s> 48 bytes

```
{([(({}[({}())()])[()])]<>){<>({}())}{}<>{}}<>{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/WiNaQ6O6NhqINTQ1NTRjNaNBRKyNnWa1jR1EtLa61sauuhZM/P//39IAAA)

### Explanation

The main part of this is the following snippet that I've written:

```
([(({})[()])]<>){<>({}())}{}<>{}
```

This will do nothing if the TOS is positive and will switch stacks otherwise.  It is *super* stack unclean but it works.  Now the main part of the program subtracts increasingly large numbers from the input until the input is non-positive.  We start the accumulator at 1 each time subtracting 1 more than the accumulator from the input.

```
({}[({}())()])
```

We can put that inside the snippet above

```
([(({}[({}())()])[()])]<>){<>({}())}{}<>{}
```

That is put in a loop so it executes until we switch stacks.  Once the loop finishes we retrieve the accumulator by switching stacks and removing the junk.

Comment: [Some more competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152670/69059)

Answer (score 2):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 49 bytes

```
....)....
...2)2...
..)1/)8..
.)1/)IE/.
@^)1_+/i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/Xw8INEEEFxAbaRpBWJqG@poWIBaI4emqr8flEKdpGK@tn6n3/7@RMQA)

#### How it works

Triangularity requires the code to have a triangular distribution of the dots. That is, the length of each row must be equal the number of rows multiplied by 2 and decremented, and each row must have (on each side) a number of dots equal to its position in the program (the bottom row is row 0, the one above it is row 1 and so forth). There are only a couple of commands, and any character other than those listed on the 'Wiki / Commands' page is treated as a no-op (extraneous dots don't make affect the program in any way, as long as the overall shape of the program stays rectangular).

Note that for two-argument commands, I've used **a** and **b** throughout the explanation. Keeping that in mind, let's see what the actual program does, after removing all the extraneous characters that make up for the padding:

```
)2)2)1/)8)1/)IE/@^)1_+/i | Input from STDIN and output to STDOUT.

)                        | Push a 0 onto the stack. Must precede integer literals.
 2                       | Push ToS * 10 + 2 (the literal 2, basically).
  )2                     | Again, push a 2 onto the stack. This can be replaced by D
                         | (duplicate), but then the padding would discard the saving.
    )1                   | Literal 1.
      /                  | Division. Push b / a (1 / 2).
       )8)1              | The literal 8 and the literal 1 (lots of these!).
           /             | Division. Push b / a (1 / 8).
            )IE          | Get the 0th input from STDIN and evaluate it.
               /         | Divide it by 1 / 8 (multiply by 8, but there isn't any
                         | operand for multiplication, and I'm not willing to add one).
                @        | Add 1 to the result.
                 ^       | Exponentiation. Here, it serves as a square too.
                  )1_+   | Decrement (add literal -1).
                      /  | Divide (by 2).
                       i | Cast to an integer.
```

An alternate solution, and shorter if padding would not be necessary:

```
....)....
...2)1...
../DD)I..
.E/)4)1/.
+^s_+i...
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/Xw8INEEEFxAbaRpCWPouLpqeIJarvqaJpqG@Hpd2XHG8diZQ9v9/I2MA)

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell 3.0, 45 bytes

```
[math]::Sqrt(2*$args[0]+.25)-.5-replace'\..*'
```

The math call hurt and PS's banker's rounding is the actual devil (hence needing regex to truncate to save a byte) but this seems pretty alright.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
ŒPfŒṗṪL
```

Runs roughly in **O(2<sup>n</sup>)** time.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//xZJQZsWS4bmX4bmqTP8yMFLCtcW8w4figqxH/w)

#### How it works

```
ŒPfŒṗṪL  Main link. Argument: n

ŒP       Powerset; yield all subarrays of [1, ..., n], sorted by length.
   Œṗ    Yield all integer partitions of n.
  f      Filter; keep subarrays that are partitions.
     Ṫ   Tail; extract the last result.
      L  Compute its length.
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```js
n=>(8*n+1)**.5-1>>1
```

-3 bytes thank to ETHproductions.

---

### Try it

```js
o.innerText=(f=
n=>(8*n+1)**.5-1>>1
)(i.value=1000000000);oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

---

### Explanation

Multiply the input by 8 and add 1, raise that to the power of .5, giving us the square root, subtract 1 and bitshift the result right by 1.

Comment: Can you include an explanation? I haven't done Javascript in a while

Comment: How bout `n=>(8*n+1)**.5-1>>1` to save 3 bytes? (haven't tested)

Comment: I outgolfed this in JS: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152558/21830

Comment: @ETHproductions - looks like that works, thanks.

Comment: @tfbninja, I'd have thought t fairly self-explanatory but explanation added.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

Kinda boring, but it<s>'s quite shorter than the other Haskell solution and</s> has a really nice pointfree expression. Unfortunately I couldn't get it any shorter without the type system getting in the way:

```hs
g x=floor$sqrt(2*x+0.25)-0.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcM7DoAgDADQq3Rw8BMJwTDi4klIrEjEoqUDt0df8k5fLkyptQDVHSln7srL0puxTloZO8xa2Xb7SOAgoGyZBEkKrKuDhyMJKAh/Rr83s3w)

#### Pointfree, 33 bytes

```hs
ceiling.(-0.5+).sqrt.(0.25+).(2*)
```

#### Alternatively, 33 bytes

Same length as the pointfree version, but much more interesting.

```hs
g n=sum[1|x<-scanl1(+)[1..n],n>x]
```

Comment: [I managed to tie the formula](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152533/68615) by fixing some dumb mistakes!

Comment: @totallyhuman: Nice, now yours is much nicer too :)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2/3, 32 bytes

Python implementation of the closed form formula

```
lambda n:int((sqrt(1+8*n)-1)//2)
```

The integer division `//2` rounds towards zero, so no `floor( )` required

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Does this need `from math import sqrt` to work? If so, it should be included in the bytecount. (In that case `lambda n:int((math.sqrt(1+8*n)-1)//2)
import math` [is a little shorter.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjOvREMjN7EkQ6@4sKhEw1DbQitPU9dQU1/fSJMrM7cgv6hEAST9v6AIpDRNw0hT8z8A))

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjOvREPDQitP21BTS0vPVNdQUx@oIr9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVXDyEDTiouzoAioViFTRyFNI1PzPwA "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Yes, it needs the import to work, so that should be included in the byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Milky Way](https://github.com/zachgates/Milky-Way), 12 bytes

```
'8*1+g1-2/v!
```

### Explanation

```
code         explanation       value

'            push input        n          
 8*          push 8, multiply  8n
   1+        add 1             8n+1
     g       square root       sqrt(8n+1)
      1-     subtract 1        sqrt(8n+1)-1
        2/   divide by 2       (sqrt(8n+1)-1)/2
          v  floor             floor((sqrt(8n+1)-1)/2)
           ! output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>7</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
Đř△>Ʃ
```

Explanation:

```
                      Implicit input
Đř△                   Gets a list of the first N triangle numbers
   >                  Is N greater than each element in the list? (returns an array of True/False)
    Ʃ                 Sums the list (autoconverts booleans to ints)
```

---

Faster, but longer way

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>11</s> 9 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
Đ2*√⌈ř△>Ʃ
```

Explanation:

```
Đ2*√⌈ř△           Gets a list of triangle numbers up to the ceiling(sqrt(2*N))-th
       >          Is N greater than each element of the list? (returns an array of True/False)
        Ʃ         Sums the array
```

---

Alternative way - port of [Shaggy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152535/77078)

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
8*⁺√⁻2÷
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
2&!inv<.@-*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8FITTEzr8xGz0FX639qcka@QpqCoYKRgrGCiYKpgpmCuYKFgqWCoYGCoaGCoZGCoTGQDQP/AQ)

```
2&!inv       solve [x choose 2 = input]
         -*  minus 1
      <.     and floor
```

Comment: I like that trick with `*` to produce 1

Answer (score 1):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 111 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_0][T   N
T   T   _Read_integer_from_STDIN][T T   T   _Retrieve_input][S S S T    S S S N
_Push_8][T  S S N
_Multiply][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S S T   T   N
_Push_n=-1][N
S S N
_Create_Label_SQRT_LOOP][S S S T    N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][S N
S _Duplicate_n][S N
S _Duplicate_n][T   S S N
Multiply][S T   S S T   S N
_Copy_0-based_2nd_(the_input)][S S S T  N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][T   S S T   _Subtract][N
T   T   N
_If_negative_jump_to_Label_SQRT_LOOP][S S S T   S N
_Push_2][T  S S T   _Subtract][S S S T  S N
_Push_2][T  S T S _Integer_divide][T    N
S T _Print_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QQDIA2EuTpCoAkhUAQQ4Obm4UETAPE4owYkkwwlmcIIFwMZwwlhACFT9/7@hAQwAAA) (with raw spaces, tabs, and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

Uses the formula:

$$f_n = \left\lfloor\frac{\sqrt{8n + 1} - 1}{2}\right\rfloor$$

NOTE: Whitespace doesn't have a square-root builtin, so we have to do this manually.

```
Integer i = read STDIN as integer
i = i * 8 + 1
Integer n = -1
Start SQRT_LOOP:
  n = n + 1
  If(n*n < i+1):
    Go to next iteration of SQRT_LOOP
n = (n - 2) integer-divided by 2
Print n as integer to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 16 bytes

```
2*14/+12/^12/-_N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ssKa78/99Iy9BEX9vQSD8OiHXj/f4DhYwB)

Might as well add my own contribution to the mix. This is shorter than the partition iterations solution in Vitsy.

Answer (score 0):

## [Oasis](https://github.com/Adriandmen/Oasis), 14 bytes

```
n8*1+1tm1%_b+0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08sziz@/z/PQstQ27Ak11A1Pknb4P///4YGBgYA)

**How?**

```
n8*1+           8n + 1
     1tm        sqrt
        1%_     integer?
           b+   add f(n-1)

             0  f(0) is 0
```

This is a recursive solution that increments the result when it encounters a triangular index, starting with 0 for the input 0.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 19(++) bytes

```perl
$_=0|-.5+sqrt$_*2+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tagRlfPVLu4sKhEJV7LSNvw/39DAxj4l19QkpmfV/xftwAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 27 bytes

Three for the price of one. I am disappointed that I can't go shorter.

```ruby
->n{a=0;n-=a+=1while n>a;a}
```

```ruby
->n{((8*n+1)**0.5-1).div 2}
```

```ruby
->n{((n-~n)**0.5-0.5).to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOtHWwDpP1zZR29awPCMzJ1Uhzy7ROrGWCySnoZGnW5enqaVloGeqC8SaeiX58ZkwOQutPG1DqKShpl5KZpmCUe3/AoW0aEMDGIjlKlDQMNTTA4po6uUmFiiopf0HAA) (to select the function, add f= in front of it)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 6 bytes

```
8*h,te
```

[Try it here!](https://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=8%2ah%2Cte&input=23&warnings=0&hex=0)

```
8      - Push literal 8.
 *     - Multiply by the input.
  h    - Increment.
   ,   - Square root.
    t  - Decrement.
     e - Floor halve.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), 41 bytes

```swift
import Foundation
{Int(sqrt($0*8+1)-1)/2}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f8/M7cgv6hEwS2/NC8lsSQzP48rJ7VEIc222jOvRKO4sKhEQ8VAy0LbUFPXUFPfqPZ/Wn6RQqZCZp6CoZ6ejZFBdUFRJlBhpk6ahkt@aVJOqkampqZOcWpBYlFiSX6RlVJMiZJm7X8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 8 bytes

```
8*hrt2/#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/99CK6OoxEhf@f///5aWAA)**

Uses the closed formula `(sqrt(8n + 1) - 1) / 2`:

```
8*          \ Multiply by 8
  h         \ Increment
   r        \ Integer root
    t       \ Decrement
     2/     \ Floordiv by 2
       #    \ Output
```

I thought I recognised this formula - it's the reverse of the function for a triangle number:

```
f(x) = (x + 1)(x / 2)
f-1(x) = (sqrt(8x+ 1) - 1) / 2
```

...which makes sense as we're counting integer sums.

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 12 bytes

```
L,ßR¬+A€<€!s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99H5/D8oENrtB0fNa2xAWLF4v8uOsmJOTk6DjqGsVxcLjqlealliSAulwIQKKkrpThklYEksvIz83QcoOJArdUQlbVgvrGRs4oXSFVJanGJjhVEkZEB0DK4cpAttU6xCBknZwenZDD30OJqkOm1ef//5ReUZObnFf/X1c3MLcjJTM4sATKLC1KTM9MqbUGGAwA)

Because closed form solutions are boring

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 22 bytes

```
⌊√(1+8*#)/2-.5⌋&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7/1FP16OOWRqG2hZaypr6Rrp6po96utX@p0Ubmsb@/69bUJSZVwIA)

Answer (score 0):

**c++,61**

```
int f(int n){for(int i=1;;i){if(n<i) return i-1; else n-=i}}
```

Comment: Consider adding a short explanation of your code (see the other answers for examples). Code-only answers like this tend to get flagged automatically as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 16 bytes

```
.(@sI1-?s.O@s)W\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/19Pw6HY01DXvljP36FYMzzm/39DAxgAAA)

```
    . (
    @ s
I 1 - ? s . O @
s ) W \ . . . .
    . .
    . .
```

[Watch it run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=LihAc0kxLT9zLk9AcylXXA==&input=MTAw&speed=20)

- `I1` set up the stack with ***n*** and 1 (incrementer)
- `-?` subtract the incrementer from ***n*** and test result

  - if result 0 `sO@`, swap result with incrementer, output and halt
  - if result negative `s(O`, swap result with incrementer, decrement, output and via a few commands, halt
  - if result positive `\s)W`, redirect, swap result with incrementer, increment and redirect back into the subtract/test